# MVC4 can't find shared layout page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC4 web application that i'm adjusting. Currently a controller loads `Index.cshtml`. In that file i have the following line:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout-DoubleColumn.cshtml";
}
```

So i changed that line to:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout-TripleColumn.cshtml";
}
```

I also copied to `_Layout-DoubleColumn.cshtml` file and renamed that to `_Layout-TripleColumn.cshtml`.

Now when i run the application i get the following error message:

> The layout page "~/Views/Shared/_Layout-TripleColumn.cshtml" could not
>   be found at the following path:
>   "~/Views/Shared/_Layout-TripleColumn.cshtml"

I have no clue what the problem could be, because i'm sure that the file is in the `Shared` folder...

[image]

Anyone any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Have you try after rebuild the solution

Comment: @Amit Yes, i did a clean and then rebuild all. But no success.

Comment: What is the Build Action on the file?

Comment: Any stacktrace? Put it here.

Comment: have you tried to unload the file from the project then add again

Comment: Have you created this view inside in any area?

Comment: Is there a white space between '-' and T ?

Comment: Do you have any areas defined?

Comment: @CodeCaster Wow that was it. The Build Action must be set to "Embedded Resource". Could you please provide that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the Build Action of the file is set to Content in the properties of the View.